# How to send reminder email to users who did not opened an uploaded document in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint online and I am trying to understand how it works.
I have managed to create a document library and inside I have few word documents uploaded.

What I want:

1. **Sent reminders/alerts to users who didn't open a document file that had been shared with them**. Lets say I have uploaded a word file "info.docx" into a library called "Team Documents". There are 3 members that have restricted permissions (only read) and two of them saw the file. I want after 5 days to send an alert to the user that didn't viewed the file.
2. **Create reports** with the below information:

```
-> Who viewed a specific document and when(date)
   Example: user1 viewed doc1 and doc2 on 1st of February 
            user2 viewed doc1 on 23rd of July, viewed doc2 on 12th of June, viewed doc3 on 12th of September

-> Who has not yet opened the document
   Example: user1 didn't viewed doc3
            user3 didn't viewed doc1, doc2 and doc3
```

Lets say I have 3 documents in a library and 3 users.

User1 viewed doc1 and doc2.

User2 viewed doc1, doc2 and doc3.

User3 didn't saw any document.

Is there any possible way to have this kind of functionality in SharePoint Online?

Are there any useful add-ins or tools that can help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knoeledge, I'm afraid there is no place to set send alerts to users who didn't open the file shared with them and get reprts on the users who has not yet opened the document.

As an alternative, in Onedrive, we can turn on "Email notification when the link in a sharing email you sent was clicked". You will get notificated if the user clicked the link in the sharing email.
[image]

In [O365 Security&Complaince](https://protection.office.com/), you can create alert policy to get alerts if a file was accessed or downloaded by specific people.
[image]

To get reports on Who viewed a specific document and when, you can go to [Microsoft 365 Compliance](https://compliance.microsoft.com/) > Audit > Set date and time range > select Activities as Accessed file > type in file name and click search.
[image]